# Pandas How to combine multiple data columns and output as dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am working on csv file.
The csv table file structure is as

| brands | models | 2021_price | 2020_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chevrolet | Traverse | 320000 | 24000 |
| chevrolet | Equinox | 23000 | 18000 |
| chevrolet | Trailblazer | 13000 | 14000 |

this is what I tried on my own

```
json_dict = {}
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    data=(
        {row[0]:{
        ''.join(str(row[1])):
            {
             "2021":' '.join(str(row[2]).split()),
             '2020':' '.join(str(row[3]).split()),
            }
        }
        }
    )
    json_dict.update(data)
```

I got this as an output

```
 {
      "chevrolet":{
         "Traverse":{
            "2021":"320000",
            "2020":"24000",
         },
      
         "chevrolet":{
         "Equinox":{
            "2021":"23000",
            "2020":"18000",
           
         } 
   }
```

but expected dictionary is as

```
{
      "chevrolet":{
         "Traverse":{
            "2021":"320000",
            "2020":"24000"
         },
      
         "Equinox":{
            "2021":"23000",
            "2020":"18000"
         } 
   }
```

this is sample of file

```
NISSAN    Patrol Platinum City  1,260,000,000.00 UZS   Nan      
    NISSAN       Qasgqai        315,000,000.00 UZS    315,000,
    NISSAN       X-Trail        367,500,000.00 UZS     Nan
```

Comment: Can you also include the `csv` in plain text verbatim from file please?

Comment: verbitem mean? I did not get it

Comment: an exact copy. just copy and paste the file please

Comment: added table structure of file the file is very large think I hope I clarified you

Comment: Is that the `csv`? there are no commas. and `nan` seems like a `pandas` value

Comment: the nan means empty I just tried making easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to group by "brands" and then create a dictionary:

```py
out = {}
for b, g in df.groupby("brands"):
    out[b] = {
        row["models"]: {
            "2020": row["2020_price"],
            "2021": row["2021_price"],
        }
        for _, row in g.iterrows()
    }

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "chevrolet": {
        "Traverse": {"2020": 24000, "2021": 320000},
        "Equinox": {"2020": 18000, "2021": 23000},
        "Trailblazer": {"2020": 14000, "2021": 13000},
    }
}
```